# Focus after comment - bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

After writing a comment (I'm using Firefox) and hitting [Enter], I can't use the arrow keys or page-up/page-down keys anymore to view the post (move the text up and down). I used to be able to use these keys.

I should probably ask this question somewhere else, but where?

Comment: this is the correct place to ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I can't explain Firefox's very bad behavior here (continuing to focus a hidden field)...it is fixed in the next build, we manually tell that `<textarea>` to lose focus on a successful comment submission now.

Comment: Sounds good. I was going to propose a manual setfocus() to a link close-by. Hey, I just saw it works!

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm this happens in Firefox; it does *not* happen in Google Chrome or IE9. (latest versions in all cases)